# Renders in python but not in kivy language

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

This code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     self.cols = 2
     self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
     self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
     self.add_widget(self.username)
     self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
     self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
     self.add_widget(self.password)


class MyApp(App):

 def build(self):
     return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
 MyApp().run()
```

Works as expected and produces this window (*window is a bit resized*):

[image]

---

However when implementing the same example in the [kivy language](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html) It fails:

**Python file:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv file:**

```
#:kivy 1.0

<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            multiline: False

        Label:
            text: "Password"
        TextInput:
            multiline: False
```

Produces *(A bit resized again)*:

[image]

Why is this and How can I possibly fix it?

Comment: Check out answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215337/kivy-base-application-has-strange-alignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need create `GridLayout` in kivy file.

Remove `GridLayout:` from the `my.kv` file as follow:

```
#:kivy 1.0

<LoginScreen>:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        text: "Username"
    TextInput:
        multiline: False

    Label:
        text: "Password"
    TextInput:
        multiline: False
```

Otherwise, another GridLayout inside LoginScreen is created.

Comment: how to run the application in hiddden mode in kivy?

Comment: @sam, I don't know about it. How about post a separated question?

Comment: yes i did : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719383/run-the-application-in-background-in-kivy