# Handling app suspend/resume on Android in Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I started developing an app with Kivy for Android and managed to build and run an APK today.

Couldn't find a straight answer on how to handle my app being suspended and resumed by a user without going through the initialization/loading screen? Is there a special mechanism that will handle this?

It is rather annoying that every time I send the app to the background and bring focus back to it there is that loading screen popping up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run the application in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719383/run-the-application-in-background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used Kivy or developed for android, but I was able to find:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719383/run-the-application-in-background-in-kivy)

From the link:

> If you just want your app to not be closed completely (so that it doesn't restart entirely with the splash screen etc. every time), you just have to add an on_pause method to your App class, and it should return True. You can also do any pre-pause stuff in this method. However, the app doesn't really keep running, it just keeps memory state.

If you want it to do computations in the background you can use Python-for-android.

Comment: This is correct. As a note to the OP, this just lets android apply its normal app pausing, which does *not* guarantee persistence - android could later kill your paused app at any time if it needs the memory or whatever. If you need to save any state, you can put the saving functions in that on_pause function before returning `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Kivy has an [`on_pause`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.on_pause) and [`on_resume`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.on_resume) methods that you can use to handle these events. These are methods of the main `App` class that are called automatically for you.