# Kivy app GUI goes black upon pause on android

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I have a simple app that I've built using buildozer and it runs mostly fine, except that whenever the app is paused (say, by pressing the home button), when resuming it the GUI goes totally black. The app does not crash (nothing shows up on logcat), and it looks like the widgets are still there somehow, because touching the screen where a TextInput widget is supposed to be brings up the keyboard. So it seems to be running normally, but it just stops rendering somehow. What can be causing this? I've tried using both the last stable kivy version and the master one, but the result is the same.

Here are my spec, main.py and kv files (do bear in mind that I'm a programming dilletante, so you will probably see some really bad programming practices in there, but bear with me):

```
main: 
kv: 
spec:
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547353/handling-app-suspend-resume-on-android-in-kivy).

Comment: Thanks, but AFAIK nowadays the on_pause method is implemented by default. What actually just solved my problem was this: Config.set('kivy','pause_on_minimize', 1)