# Python, kivy, android apk. Clock.schedule_interval stops working on the phone

Tags: python, kivy, clock

Python, kivy, android apk. Clock.schedule_interval stops working on the phone when minimizing the application (switching to the main screen, launching another application).

It needs to work all the time.
I would like the application is not unloaded from memory

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547353/handling-app-suspend-resume-on-android-in-kivy).