# Kivy App In Background (No Gui, Service)

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

I have a main app. It downloads some data and works with it. But if the app is closed i also want to get a notification about the data. I.e. When a new Newstime Online post is published.

How can i do that with python (and the module plyer is requiered)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plyer is a Python library for accessing features of your hardware / platforms.
Pyjnius is a Python library for accessing Java classes.

The strategy will have to involve getting Pyjnius toast notifications.
You will also need to use kivy events. Setup event listeners.
You will also need to read inclement's answer on runnning a app in background
[Run the application in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719383/run-the-application-in-background-in-kivy)

This is not exhaustive but should get you started.